# What does "the first" async method look like?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

If an `async` method "A" has to `await` on another `async` method "B", and the method "B" has to `await` on another `async` method "C", how does the method "C" - "the first" `async` method - look like? I googled the question "How to create an `async` method". All the examples I got is like...the method "C" has some code like "Task.Run()" inside. I am badly confused. `Task.Run()` is for CPU-bound only, isn't it? But `async` method is usually for I/O bound operations. Can someone please explain this to me?

Comment: have a look at [TaskCompletionSource<TResult>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskcompletionsource-1?view=netframework-4.8)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many of them are wrapping the vanilla asynchronous styled methods that take callback delegate which will be called when it is completed.

Note that not only `Task` but also all instances of types that match the following rules could be `await`ed:

- There must be a `AWAITER GetAwaiter()` method callable from the `await`ed instance (which meas an extension method is also accepted), while the `AWAITER` represents any types that match the rules.
- `AWAITER` must implement `INotifyCompletion` to accept a callback delegate that should be called on the asynchronous task is completed.
- `AWAITER` instance must have a `bool IsCompleted { get; }` defined to check if it is completed.
- `AWAITER` instance must have a `RESULT GetResult()` method defined to finish `await`ing, while `RESULT` would be the result type of the `await` expression which could be `void` if no result is returned.

For example:

```
public static TaskAwaiter<T> GetAwaiter<T>(this T target) => Task.FromResult(target).GetAwaiter();
```

This method enabled all types to be `await`ed, that would complete instantly resulting the value itself.

```
var x = await 1;  // int x = 1;
```

Any types that match the rules could be `await`ed, which means you can implement it by yourself to invoke the callback delegate manually without an asynchronous method.

The standard API provides [`TaskCompletionSource<TResult>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskcompletionsource-1) for wrapping callback asynchronous operations to `Task`, and you may not need to implement your own awaitable type, but knowing what `await` syntax actually does enable you to handle more cases.